# how to read large amount (28 characters) of Bluetooth LE peripheral name-key ad data every time by central didDiscoverPeripheral method?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

How can I send 28 bytes of peripheral name-key ad data and receive it by the central?

Normally, with the UUID, there's only room for 8 characters in the peripheral name key ad data.

But there's this TRICK:
I discovered if my name key has 28 characters, the central ad data is empty, BUT all 28 characters all appear one time in the central's didDiscoverPeripheral's peripherl.name variable.  But the next time the central scans same device, it gets instead the GATT value of "iPad" (because my central and peripheral are on two iPad minis.)

Apple Doc. says it normally sends the GATT, but I observe that it always sends the 28-char name once.

BACKGROUND:
I want to put identification data in the peripheral's ad data, to avoid a read-value interchange.  The reason is to have the shortest communication interchange between devices, to save time and battery.

I've tried turning scanning off then back on, and stopping and re-starting advertising.  Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not going to work. Once you connect, the device name characteristic is read by CoreBluetooth and it will be used as the name for the peripheral later on. The only place the name you set will always appear is the advertisement data:

```
(lldb)po advertisementData

{
    kCBAdvDataChannel = 37;
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataLocalName = MyPeripheral;
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        "Unknown (<e20a39f4 73f54bc4 a12f17d1 ad07a961>)"
    );
}
```

The device name characteristic cannot be accessed in an iOS device in any way.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the Bluetooth LE controller has a parameter set to filter duplicates. You may need HCI layer access to change this if you don't have API calls to the HCI "set scan enable" command. See Bluetooth Core Specification v4.0 Vol 2 Part E 7.8.11